# Request to Php file from node js and i am getting the error 404 not found and i tried every possible path but not getting it

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Error in the Browser is :
[image]

My request code in js file is :

```
$http.post('php/db-r-distinct.php', zd)
                .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Constructor, Partners response : ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
                _this.$scope.dem = response.data; // on récupère ici les données du php 
            });
```

My php file is placed in a folder src/php/db-r-distinct.php

```
<?php
include 'gs.php';

try {
    $mysql = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".SQL_DBASE.";host=".SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
    $mysql->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $mysql->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

}
catch (PDOException $e) {echo 'Error :' . $e->getMessage();}
$dd = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$tab = $dd ->tab;
$distct = $dd ->distinctv;
$sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM $tab AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT $distct, MAX(du) AS latest FROM $tab GROUP BY $distct
) AS t2
ON t1.$distct = t2.$distct AND t1.du = t2.latest ORDER BY t1.du DESC";
$c = array();
$r=$mysql->query($sql);
while($row=$r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $c[]=$row;
}
$r->closeCursor();
exit(json_encode($c));
?>
```

My folder structure is :
BackendWe/src/php/db-r-distinct.php

my php file run here

```
'http://localhost/BackendWe-master/src/php/db-r-distinct.php'
```

but when i adding  in request in js file  i get error

[image]

so here what is the error for path of the php file then how i define the path in node environment .
How do i get data from php file in node js ?
node js running on localhost:3000 and php on apache server localhost only

Path of the project is :
BackendWE/src/php/all php files 
BackendWE/src/index.html
BackendWE/src/js/all the controllers here

Comment: Can you define the path of your project exact location

Comment: Your error is in the URL: `php/db-r-distinct.php`. But we can't help you any further because we don't know where your webpage is stored.

Comment: i only need to get data from php files in node ,is it a port issue of node and apache?

Comment: is you are able to access your php file without nodejs? like `localhost/php/yourfile.php`

Answer (score 0):

You are having a [cors issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

You can simply add at the top of each files you want to request :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

or add global configuration with [Apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) for example.

And your POST request path must be `BackendWe-master/src/php/db-r-distinct.php` rather than `php/db-r-distinct.php`.